# Error in building an angular application - Issue in the theme sheet

Tags: angular, angular-material

As a beginner in the angular, I am learning the theming concept in angular. However, when I have come up with my own style sheet, there is an error thrown while doing the 'ng serve'.

[image]

This is my style sheet.

[image]

Can someone please help me understand what exactly is wrong here?

Comment: Why are you using an unknown `mat-theme-experimental` mixin? This mixin isn't defined anywhere in the SCSS code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I was able to find the issue. I had to modify it in the following manner

```
$my-theme: mat-light-theme($my-primary, $my-accent, $my-warn)
```

That solved my issue !!!